# How can I exclude SKAdvisorResources.bundle from being copied within the app?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, skmaps

Given I don't need the bundle SKAdvisorResources because I don't use any voice advice or navigation, how can I avoid it ends up in my ipa?

I've added SKMaps to my project as pod dependency just adding pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK' to my Podfile.

The solution I've come up with is to add a custom script phase to my project which removes the bundle before it gets exported; this is safe if you want to update your pods but I don't really like, I'd prefer to specify some exclusion rule in my Podfile but I don't know if this is possible...

```
rm -rf "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/SKAdvisorResources.bundle"
rm -rf "${INSTALL_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/SKAdvisorResources.bundle"
```

Comment: Right now that should work - when updating the pod we'll look into making the SKAdvisorResources bundle an optional package

Comment: @Ando I've updated cocoapods to version 1.0.0 and now my workaround doesn't work. How long before a new version with the bundle as optional dependency? Do you have any suggestion for fix the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @yeradis suggestion my final solution cycles through the aggregated list of targets defined in the podfile and apply the replacement to all file.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
        puts("* Commenting file `#{target.label}-resources.sh` lines having `SKAdvisorResources.bundle`")

        system("find . -name \"#{target.label}-resources.sh\" -exec sed -i '' -e \"/SKAdvisorResources.bundle/s/^/#/\" {} +")
    end
end
```

Note that `target.label` returns a string including the `Pods-` prefix

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question and probably you got a solution(or decided to use another library)

but just in case for future references

> **THIS WORKS ON MacOS** *for other systems you need to check your available tools `find`, `sed`*

you can comment that line with something like this at your `Podfile`

```
post_install do |installer|    
    app_target = "your_target_goes_here"
    puts("* Commenting file `Pods-#{app_target}-resources.sh` line having `SKAdvisorResources.bundle`")
    system("find . -name \"Pods-#{app_target}-resources.sh\" -exec sed -i '' -e \"/SKAdvisorResources.bundle/s/^/#/\" {} +")
end
```

Lets add a little explanation here in case and update is needed xD

Explanation:

- `/SKAdvisorResources.bundle/` matches a line with
  *SKAdvisorResources.bundle* in it
- `s` perform a substitution on the lines matched above
- if something match, then will insert the hash character `#`
  at the beginning of the line `^`

Comment: Thanks, that's a brilliant idea!

Comment: @AlessioNunzi just made an update for a second time, now its better, cause something as simple as updating cocoapoad broke my first version xD